# Laravel Migrations - Dropping columns

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to drop the column `UserDomainName` from my database table `clients`.

At first I installed `doctrine/dbal` by executing `composer require doctrine/dbal` followed by `composer update`, like described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#columns).

Then I created the migration which I want to use to drop the column:

```
php artisan make:migration remove_user_domain_name_from_clients --table=clients
```

I added `Schema::dropColumn('UserDomainName');` to the `down()` method:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class RemoveDomainName extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            Schema::dropColumn('UserDomainName');
        });
    }
}
```

However, I get

```
Migrating: 2017_08_22_135145_remove_user_domain_name_from_clients
Migrated:  2017_08_22_135145_remove_user_domain_name_from_clients
```

after executing `php artisan migrate` but no Column is dropped.
If I execute it again I get `Nothing to migrate.`

Comment: Why did you add `dropColumn` to the `down` method? Shouldn't it be part of the `up` method?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The `down` function is used for rollbacks, you have to add this `dropColumn` in the `up` function because it is an action you want to perform when running migrations.

So, in your `up` function there should be:

```
Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('UserDomainName');
});
```

And in the `down` function you should do the inverse, add the column back:

```
Schema::table('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('UserDomainName');
});
```

This way, you can always return to any point in the migrations.

Comment: I think the `dropIfExists` function only applies to entire tables.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it, now I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlBuilder::dropColumn()` i try to resolve this problem then I try your solution again.

Comment: Have you used the code I posted? Because in your example you are using the function statically on the `Schema` class, which will not work.

Comment: DON'T use `dropIfExists('column')` that drops the Entire table! @Jeff

Comment: _This way, you can always return to any point in the migrations._. 
This is not true. If you drop a column you can't get back the data. Also keep in mind that if you try to add back a non nullable field the query will fail

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1: use one line solution

> This solution is tested on Laravel 9.x, it might not work in the lower version

Inside the `down` method of migration file use [Schema::dropColumns](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_dropColumns) method, the first arguments would be table name, and second arguments in columns name that you want to drop in array.

```php
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropColumns("tablename", ["column"]);
}
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#dropping-columns)

#### Solution 2: Another Approach

Here, [$table->dropColumn](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_dropColumn) accepts colum name either in array or string.

```php
public function down()
{
    Schema::table("tablename", function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['columnname']);
        // OR 
        $table->dropColumn('columnname');
    });
}
```

Comment: @Pathros my bad, updated as accordingly. Thanks,

Comment: Just tested on v9.41, dropColumns() is working, dropColumn() doesn't work.

Comment: both [dropColumns](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Builder.html#method_dropColumns) & [dropColumn](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_dropColumn) are exists

Comment: then what is the command? `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Answer (score -5):

To dropColumn , You can do like this

In your down function there should be:

```
 public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('UserDomainName');
        });
    }
```

Then run
php artisan migrate:rollback

That's it.

Comment: I don't think this goes in the down method